# Jquery Loop Table Rows. Replace if match or add new row

Tags: jquery, rows

I'm trying to work out how to loop through a tables rows and if a row contains a specific entry replace that row only.. but if no rows contain the entry add a new row.

So far I've got:

```
$("#list tr:not(.hdr)").each(function(){
      if( $(this).text().indexOf(ID) >= 0 )
          $(this).replaceWith(row);
});
```

This works, if it find a match for the `ID` it replaces that row, but if there are no matches how do I add a new row ?

I've tried this, but it didn't work:

```
var replaceRow = '';
$("#list tr:not(.hdr)").each(function(){
      if( $(this).text().indexOf(ID) >= 0 )
          var replaceRow = $(this);
});

if (replaceRow.length > 1) {
      $(replaceRow).replaceWith(row)
} else {
     $('#list').find('.hdr').last('tr').after(row);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you can use `append(row)` if `row` is a `tr` object

Comment: Adding or replacing the row works. the issue I have is determining if the row needs to be replaced or a new row added.

Comment: remove `var` from `var replaceRow = $(this);` as `replaceRow ` is a global variable
`